# ES exists query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a document which has `nested field`:

- `testData.testDataId`

I only want to get the documents that have `testData.testDataId` as `null`

Here is my query:

```json
{
  "bool": {
    "must_not": [
      { "exists": { "field": "testData.testDataId", "boost": 1.0 } }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
    "boost": 1.0
  }
}
```

But I've got and those documents which has **'testData' as null** too. Is it possible disable?

For example:
I have those 3 documents

```json
[
  {
    "name": "test_user_1",
    "additionalInfo": { "phoneNumber": "00000000", "address": "test_address" },
    "testData": { "testDataId": "some_id", "description": "test_description" }
  },
  {
    "name": "test_user_2",
    "additionalInfo": { "phoneNumber": "00000000", "address": "test_address" },
    "testData": { "description": "test_description" }
  },
  {
    "name": "test_user_3",
    "additionalInfo": { "phoneNumber": "00000000", "address": "test_address" }
  }
]
```

I wish to only retrieve `test_user_2`

Comment: Could you give a sample of documents and the expected results ?

Comment: Sure, for example, I have these objects:

Comment: {
 "name": "test_user_1",
 "additionalInfo": {
  "phoneNumber": "00000000",
  "address": "test_address"
 },
 "testData":{
  "testDataId": "some_id",
  "description: "test_description"
 }
},
{
 "name": "test_user_2",
 "additionalInfo": {
  "phoneNumber": "00000000",
  "address": "test_address"
 },
 "testData":{
  "description: "test_description"
 }
},
{
 "name": "test_user_3",
 "additionalInfo": {
  "phoneNumber": "00000000",
  "address": "test_address"
 }
}

Comment: And I want to get only test_user_2

Comment: Edit your question please to make it more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Tldr;

Since you are dealing with `nested field` you need to use a nested query.

## To fix

```json
GET /72491619/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "testData",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must_not": [
            {
              "exists": {
                "field": "testData.testDataId"
                }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## To reproduce

To set up the index and the data I used the api calls below:

```json
PUT /72491619/
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "additionalInfo":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "phoneNumber": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "address": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "testData":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "testDataId": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "description": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"72491619"}}
{"name":"test_user_1","additionalInfo":{"phoneNumber":"00000000","address":"test_address"},"testData":{"testDataId":"some_id","description":"test_description"}}
{"index":{"_index":"72491619"}}
{"name":"test_user_2","additionalInfo":{"phoneNumber":"00000000","address":"test_address"},"testData":{"description":"test_description"}}
{"index":{"_index":"72491619"}}
{"name":"test_user_3","additionalInfo":{"phoneNumber":"00000000","address":"test_address"}}
```